# Executing a Route (Controller/Action) using PHP CLI and Detecting a CLI Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, command-line-interface

Is there a way in Laravel 4 to run my controller/action using PHP-CLI? I have a controller/action that I would like to extend to perform an alternative action if the request comes from the CLI, so is there a way to identify the request as a CLI request?

The Laravel documentation on [this site](https://tower.la.utexas.edu/index.php/docs/requests) seems to suggest that there is a method Request::cli() for determining if the current request is via the Artisan CLI but when I used the method in Laravel 4, it throws an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::cli()

Basically, I have just moved from CakePHP to Laravel and would like to accomplish something similar to as what's described in this article (for CakePHP) : [Calling controller actions from cron and the command line](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mathew_attlee/2006/12/05/calling-controller-actions-from-cron-and-the-command-line)

I understand that I can work with Laravel 4 Artisan Commands, but is the approach I would like to use possible?  And if so, how?

Comment: Seems like you got an older version of the manual, try: http://laravel.com/docs. ( and detecting if the app is runned from the cli: `App::runningInConsole()` )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Rob already said, to determine if the current script is being run in the console use `App::runningInConsole()` or simple plain PHP `php_sapi_name() == 'cli'`.

As for running controller@action from console, you could use `curl` or `wget` to request one of your routes but I think the proper way of doing it would be to use a [custom artisan command](http://laravel.com/docs/commands). Your controllers are classes so you can instantiate them and use as you please from within your artisan command:

```
$controller = new SomeController;
$controller->someAction();
```

Watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BviKET-QTEQ) for an introduction to easily developing your own artisan commands.